# Client has Excel 2019, I have Excel 365. Dropdowns of spilled arrays don't work for client

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, office365

The spreadsheet I've created has multiple dependent dropdowns that reference spilled arrays. Specifically, the dropdowns reference a cells that each use Filter() and Sort().

The client has Excel 2019 and reports that the dropdowns don't function. I've made sure that In-cell Dropdown is selected in Validation. I've ensured File>Options>Advanced>Display Options for this workbook has "For objects, show:" All is selected.

I'm aware that I could create a combobox to replicate the function of the dropdown, but I'm under the assumption that all other cells in the spreadsheet that use Filter() and Sort() wouldn't work.

Is that a correct assumption to make? Is there a way to have these functions work in Excel 2019? If the file were uploaded to SharePoint, would that allow the client to use the file?

Thanks for your consideration. This is my first post. I hope it was clear. If not, I will try to further clarify.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client uploaded the file to SharePoint and was able to use the file without issue. This solved the issue of the dependent dropdowns not functioning, and also made sure the rest of the file worked correctly with the Filter() and Sort() functions creating spilled arrays.